# Using UnderscoreJS with RequireJS

Tags: maven, requirejs, underscore.js, webjars

I'm trying to use/load `UnderscoreJS` `1.7.0` with `RequireJS` `2.1.14-3`. At my application startup, UnderscoreJS is well loaded, but it is "undefined". See details below:

main.js

```
define(function() {
    // Configuration of RequireJS
    requirejs.config({
        enforceDefine : true,

        map : {
            '*': { 
                ...
                'underscore' : 'webjars/underscorejs/1.7.0/underscore'
            },
        },

        // The base URL is just the top-level directory where the files are stored
        baseUrl : './',

        // Kick-start the application by loading these files
        deps : [ 'MyPanel' ],
    });
});
```

The module using it :

```
define(['ractive',
    'underscore',
    ...], 
    function(Ractive,
            _,
            ...){
var Foo = Ractive.extend({
    ...

    oninit: function(){
        var anArray = [1, 2, 3]
        _.each(anArray, function(item){
               ...
        })
    }
}
```

And the result in the browser console :
[image: Browser result]

The underscoreJS file is loaded by the browser:

[image: Module loaded]

This must be a detail, but I managed my `Javascript` dependencies with `maven`and `webjars`

So why is my `_` `undefined` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.7.0/underscore.js) of Underscore 1.7.0, you see it registers itself like this:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define('underscore', [], function() {
        return _;
    });
}
```

Note the first argument to `define`. This hardcodes the name of the module as `'underscore'`.

The problem is that you are using a `map` configuration which is not compatible with this hardcoded name. What you do is tell RequireJS "in all modules (`"*"`), when the module requires a module with the name `'underscore'`, then please return instead the module with the name `'webjars/underscorejs/1.7.0/underscore'`". So when you require `'underscore'`:

1. RequireJS looks for the module named `'webjars/underscorejs/1.7.0/underscore'` instead.
2. It uses the default path for such a module name and finds a file at that location. It loads the file and executes it.
3. However, the file contains a `define` calls that defines `'underscore'`, not `'webjars/underscorejs/1.7.0/underscore'`. So RequireJS is not able to honor the request.

Instead of `map`, you should be using a `paths` configuration for Underscore. Something like:

```
paths : {
    'underscore' : 'webjars/underscorejs/1.7.0/underscore'
}
```

This tells RequireJS something like "you'll find the module named `'underscore'` at the location `'webjars/underscorejs/1.7.0/underscore'`". When you use this, the name of the module requested and the name of the module defined match.

Comment: This should be fixed in the `1.7.0-1` or newer version of the WebJar. See: https://github.com/webjars/underscorejs/issues/12

Comment: @JamesWard How does the patch associated with that issue you link to have anything to do with `map`?

Comment: Well, it depends on if @rémi-doolaeghe is using the RequireJS feature of WebJars. If so then the RequireJS config is automatically generated from the `pom.xml` file.  If not, then you are right - it doesn't have anything to do with the issue.

Comment: @JamesWard I have given a try to your idea, but unfortunately this was not the source of the problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Louis Your solution did the trick. Thanks for the really clear explanation you provided too. I'll take a look at the subtilities between map and paths in the doc. I always thought there were really few differences, but this should not be the case. Thanks anyway for the time you used for me.